# Magento2.3 How to apply condition for specific country in checkout shipping method?

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, magento2.3

In the magento2 checkout page, I'm using a free shipping method and I need to hide all shipping methods only for specific country and postal code. Kindly share your custom module or help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create `di.xml` in `Vendor/Module/etc` folder,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface">
        <plugin name="specific_shipping_method" type="Vendor\Module\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create `ShipmentEstimationPlugin.php` in `Vendor/Module/Plugin/Quote/Api` folder,

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\Api;

use Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface;

class ShipmentEstimationPlugin
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    public function aroundEstimateByExtendedAddress(
        ShipmentEstimationInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
    ) {
        $shippingMethods = $proceed($cartId, $address);
        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
            if ($address->getCountry() == "AF" && $address->getPostalCode() == "123456") {
                foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                    unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                }
            }

            return $shippingMethods;
        }
    }
}
```

Clear cache: `php bin/magento cache:clean` and check it.

**NOTE: Set condition as per your requirements.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102833/discussion-on-answer-by-dhaduk-mitesh-magento2-3-how-to-apply-condition-for-spec).