# Magento 2.3: How to hide only free shipping methods based on postal code

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, shipping-methods

In the below code, I am hiding all shipping methods based on postal code 2nd value is 0. In this case, all shipping methods are removing. but I want to remove only free shipping. Can you explain how I can do this?

```
require(['mage/url', 'jquery','domReady!' ,'jquery/ui'],function(url , $)  {
$("[name='postcode']").live('change',function(){
    postCode = $("[name='postcode']").val();
    // console.log(postCode);
    postCode = postCode.slice(1,2);
    console.log(postCode);

            if(postCode == 0){
                    $('.checkout-shipping-method').hide();
                    message = $('#message').length;
                    if(message == 0){
                        $(.checkout-shipping-address').append("<b id=message><a href=mailto:websales@productioncase.com>Contact </a>&nbsp;Production Case for Rural Shipping<b/>");
                        $("#message").css("color","red");
                        $("#message").show();
                    }
                    else if(message){
                        ("#message").show();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $('.checkout-shipping-method').show();
                    $("#message").hide();
                }
    });
});
```

Comment: Refer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300260/magento2-3-how-to-apply-condition-for-specific-country-in-checkout-shipping-meth/300264#300264

Comment: @Yousaf Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes @SiarheyUchukhlebau. Thankyou for your concern :)

Comment: Any updates on this I am trying to do this on admin sales order

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple plugin:

> app/code/MageWorx/DisableFreeShipping/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- PLUGINS: -->
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping">
        <plugin name="mageworx_disable_free_shipping_by_postcode"
                type="MageWorx\DisableFreeShipping\Plugin\DisableFreeShippingByPostCode"
                sortOrder="20"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/MageWorx/DisableFreeShipping/Plugin/DisableFreeShippingByPostCode.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2020 MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MageWorx\DisableFreeShipping\Plugin;

/**
 * Class DisableFreeShippingByPostCode
 */
class DisableFreeShippingByPostCode
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
     * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result|bool
     */
    public function aroundCollectRates(
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
    ) {
        if ($request->getDestPostcode()) { // Check is postcode exists in request
            if ($this->postCodeContainsNullOnSecondPosition($request->getDestPostcode())) { // Check is second symbol == 0
                return false; // Disable method
            }
        }

        return $proceed($request);
    }

    /**
     * Test postcode
     *
     * @param string $postCode
     * @return bool
     */
    private function postCodeContainsNullOnSecondPosition(string $postCode): bool
    {
        return stripos($postCode, '0') === 1;
    }
}
```

Result with 0 in zip on second position and without:

[image: with 0 in zip on second position] [image: without 0 in zip]

You can add any condition for the `freeshipping` method in that plugin.

**PS:** here is [complete working code in example module](https://github.com/SiarheyUchukhlebau/MageWorx_DisableFreeShipping) on github.

Comment: can you answer this question.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310973/magento-2-3-how-to-hide-field-on-checkout-page-based-on-customer-group

Answer (score 1):

According to your question you need to hide free shipping method if 2nd value of postcode is 0, you can achieve it using below.

**app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping" type="VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php**

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

class Freeshipping extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping
{
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $postCode = $request->getDestPostcode();
        $postCode = substr($postCode, 1, 2);

        if($postCode == 0)
        {
            return false;

            // you can use this for custom error message.
            // $error = $this->_rateErrorFactory->create();
            // $error->setCarrier($this->_code);
            // $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            // $error->setErrorMessage(__('Your Error Message'));
            // return $error;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request);

        if ($request->getFreeShipping() || $request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() >= $this->getConfigData(
            'free_shipping_subtotal'
        )
        ) {
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

            $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('freeshipping');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            $method->setPrice('0.00');
            $method->setCost('0.00');

            $result->append($method);
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('showmethod')) {
            $error = $this->_rateErrorFactory->create();
            $error->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $errorMsg = $this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg');
            $error->setErrorMessage(
                $errorMsg ? $errorMsg : __(
                    'Sorry, but we can\'t deliver to the destination country with this shipping module.'
                )
            );
            return $error;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this ?  I want this on my checkout page. When i input in postcode field.

Comment: yes i have tested this, it is working as per your requirement in both cart and checkout page

Comment: Sir its not working. It is still showing free shipping.