# How to hide shipping method in admin sales order

Tags: admin, sales-order, shipping, shipping-methods

Is it possible to hide a particular shipping method based on postcode only in the admin area?

When I say admin area I mean the Sales order page in the admin section.

I have tried around a plug-in

```
<type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping">
<plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Extension_Model_Shipping" sortOrder="10"
        type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ApplyShipping"/>
```

`aroundCollectCarrierRates`

But this isn’t helping me to get it done for postcodes

I can grab the postcode by request but when I select the shipping methods the particular shipping method still shows

Please can someone guide me or help me?

I have used this as a starting guide but this hide it completely

https://meetanshi.com/blog/enable-disable-shipping-method-programmatically-in-magento-2/amp/

I have used this to grab postcode
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/301477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, I am checking the condition for the areacode also

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin;

class ApplyShipping
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
    ) {
        $this->appState = $appState;
    }

    public function aroundCollectCarrierRates(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $carrierCode,
        $request
    ) {
        // To disable the shipping method
        if ($this->appState->getAreaCode() == 'adminhtml' &&
            $request->getDestPostcode() == 'postal_code' &&
            $carrierCode == 'carrier_code') {
            return false;
        }
        // To enable the shipping method
        return $proceed($carrierCode, $request);
    }
}
```

In the Above code replace the ***postal_code*** and ***carrier_code*** according to you, for which you want to disable the shipping for that particular postal code.

Comment: this was perfect thank you so much